# selected item in query fro dropdown list in php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, drop-down-menu

Here is my code I made a script to get values in "list_cust_city" from selected item in "list_cust_name" through query in php. I didnt get any values in "list_cust_city" for city. I made *city.php*.

```
<script>
    $('#list_cust_name').change(function(){
        alert("heyyy");
        $.ajax({
            url:'city.php',
            data:{cust_name:$( this ).val()},
            success: function( data ){
                $('#list_cust_city').html( data );
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<label style="color:#000">Name </label>

<?php
    $query_name = "SELECT DISTINCT cust_name FROM customer_db ORDER BY  cust_name"; //Write a query
    $data_name = mysql_query($query_name);  //Execute the query
?>
<select id="list_cust_name" name="list_cust_name">
    <?php
        while($fetch_options_name = mysql_fetch_assoc($data_name)) { //Loop all the options retrieved from the query
        $customer=$fetch_options_name['cust_name'];
    ?> 
    <option value="<?php echo $fetch_options_name['cust_name']; ?>"><?php echo  $fetch_options_name['cust_name']; ?></option>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

*city.php*

```
<body>
    <?php
        include('dbconnect.php');
        db_connect();
        $cust_name1=$_GET['cust_name']; //passed value of cust_name
        $query_city = "SELECT DISTINCT cust_city FROM customer_db WHERE cust_name='$cust_name1'ORDER BY cust_city"; //Write a query
        $data_city = mysql_query($query_city); //Execute the query
        while($fetch_options_city = mysql_fetch_assoc($data_city)) { //Loop all the options retrieved from the query
    ?> 
    <option value="<?php echo $fetch_options_city['cust_city']; ?>"><?php echo  $fetch_options_city['cust_city']; ?></option>
    <?php
        }   
    ?>
</body>
```

Comment: you need to add second drop down in the main page

Comment: in city.php `<body>` tag is not needed

Answer (score 0):

PHP uses `.` to concat strings. Change your query to:

```
$query_city = 'SELECT DISTINCT cust_city FROM customer_db WHERE cust_name="'.$cust_name1.'"ORDER BY cust_city';
```

Also add this to your first php file:

```
<select id="list_cust_city" name="list_cust_city"></select>
```

Here's full code.

php 1:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
 $('#list_cust_name').change(function(){
     $.ajax({
            url:'city.php',
            data:{cust_name:$( this ).val()},
            success: function( data ){
                    $('#list_cust_city').html( data );
            }
     });
 });
});
</script>

<label style="color:#000">Name </label>
<?php $data_name = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT cust_name FROM customer_db ORDER BY  cust_name");?>

<select id="list_cust_name" name="list_cust_name">
<?php while($fetch_options_name = mysql_fetch_assoc($data_name)) { ?> 
<option value="<?php=$fetch_options_name['cust_name']; ?>"><?php=$fetch_options_name['cust_name']; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>

<select id="list_cust_city" name="list_cust_city"></select>
```

city.php:

```
<?php 
  include('dbconnect.php');
  db_connect();
  $cust_name1=$_GET['cust_name'];
  $data_city = mysql_query('SELECT DISTINCT cust_city FROM customer_db WHERE cust_name="'.$cust_name1.'" ORDER BY cust_city');
  while($fetch_options_city = mysql_fetch_assoc($data_city)) {
    ?> 
    <option value="<?php=$fetch_options_city['cust_city'];?>"><?php=$fetch_options_city['cust_city'];?></option>
    <?php
  }   
?>
```

Comment: I've added full code, try it. I suggest you to use ID's for customers and cities instead of string values.

Comment: Check your requests. Or can you provide some info on your customer_db table structure?

Comment: i having cust_id,cust_name,cust_city,cust_state.i want two dropdown in that one "list_cust_name" contains all cust_name if i select any of the customer in second dropdown "list_cust_city" cust_name's state shoule be appear..

Comment: i did that also i think list_cust_name change event is working but after that its not going to city.php

Answer (score 0):

You must use document ready because the DOM isn't load.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#list_cust_name').change(function(){
    alert("heyyy");
    $.ajax({
    url:'city.php',
    data:{cust_name:$( this ).val()},
    success: function( data ){
    $('#list_cust_city').html( data );
   }
  });
  });
});
```